# Cyrillic filenames converted to =_UTF8?B?_[STRINGOFGIBBERISH] while downloading in Edge.How can this be solved?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have filename in Cyrillic which can be downloaded in Chrome using same name and extension when I try to download them in Edge I get them converted in UTF8 without extension.

Comment: That looks like a "Q" encoded header, as specified in [RFC 2047](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047). You should double check whether the header is really correctly formatted according to the rules in the standard (and so Edge is just not interpreting them properly, in which case there's little else to do but file a bug) or whether there's wiggle room that might cause Edge to fall back to leaving it uninterpreted.

Comment: @JeroenMostert If filename is  in English it downloads fine.

Comment: Can you share the file name and post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, please check the Edge browser version.